# How to solve 'error creating bean' with LightAdmin?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-4.x, lightadmin

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'excursionDynamicJpaRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type int not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1090)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1740)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type int not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:100)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:814)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:399)
    at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.buildTypeVariableMap(GenericTypeResolver.java:299)
    at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(GenericTypeResolver.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.<init>(ClassTypeInformation.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(ClassTypeInformation.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.<init>(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.DefaultRepositoryMetadata.<init>(DefaultRepositoryMetadata.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepositoryMetadata(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:181)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: int
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 78 common frames omitted
```

This error was given. Then I found quite similar answer and following it, chage Entity class to:

```
@Entity
//@Table( name = "excursion_time_table" )
public class ExcursionTimeTable
{
```

But this won't help. What shall I do to implement LightAdmin with Gradle + Spring + Hibernate project?

Edit:

```
@Transactional
public interface IExcursionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Excursion, Integer>
{
}
```

Following [this example](https://github.com/la-team/lightadmin-springboot/tree/master/src/main/java/org/lightadmin/boot) I've created interface above. Then I've created default class, that implements this interface (with default values genereated by IDE). And then I've implemented some beans in the configuration.

@Bean
public ExcursionRepository excursionDynamicJpaRepository ()
{
    return new ExcursionRepository();
}

Still nothing. LightAdmin didn't started for me.

Comment: The full stack trace of the error should help to pinpoint the problem

Comment: Added full stack trace

Comment: It looks like you've declared a Spring Data JPA repository that's using an int in its type signature. That should produce a compilation error, though. Can you post your Spring Data JPA repository interface(s)?

Comment: I've added more explanation to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just played a bit with your model in a sandbox and seems like the problem is in creation of dynamic JPA repositories for entities having primitive primary key.

I've created a [ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/la-team/light-admin/issues/163) for proper resolution, but **to fix your problem, just use a numeric wrapper type (Long, etc.)**.

Comment: Yes, your answer helped. But it is still didn't start, because of following error: Error resolving template "dashboard-view", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers? It's thymeleaf error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an implementation of `IExecursionRepository`. Spring Data JPA will do that for you. Try deleting your `ExcurationRepository` class and its `@Bean` method. Spring Data JPA will automatically create a bean of type `IExcursionRepository` that can be injected into your application's classes.

You can see this in the example that you linked to in the question. The application has a `HotelRepository` interface, but doesn't implement it itself. The implementation of this interface that's automatically created by Spring Data JPA is used. For example, you can see it being injected into `ApplicationController`.

Comment: I've done it, but I've got same error. I've created implementation after I tested it, because IDE said, that there are no Beans of the IExcursionRepository was found.

Comment: That sounds like your IDE is being too clever for its own good. Can just ignore the error from your IDE or does it stop you from running your app?

Comment: It's not. I've done successful Gradle Clean Build and then deploy it on tomcat server. Application started, but LightAdmin part give me error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped then. Perhaps you can share all your code somewhere?

Comment: I've posted application on github https://github.com/Dracontis/Excursions/tree/master/src/main/java/com/dracontis/excursions

Comment: I've shared project with all directories now, it should compile now.